# Building ubuntu server packages

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I have developed some C++ apps on my Ubuntu desktop. I want to create installation packages so that I can install them on a Ubuntu server.

Can anyone provide guidelines on how to create an Ubuntu server package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to create an "install" section in your makefile which will install the program, then run `checkinstall`. You may need to install it with `aptitude install checkinstall`.

**checkinstall** runs `make install`, finds out what was changed, then builds a package based on it.

---

To do the install section in a makefile, just put the commands it would take to install your program. Here's an example of a program that creates a binary called "myprogram" and needs some configuration in /etc:

```
# make example
myprogram: main.o something_else.o
    gcc -o myprogram main.o something_else.o -llibrary_goes_here

install: myprogram
    cp myprogram /usr/bin #install binary
    cp -R etc /etc/myprogram # copy "etc" folder to /etc/myprogram
```

There's a command called `install` that's like `cp` and lets you specify permissions, but I don't know the syntax well enough.

You'd also need a section for each .o file that says how to compile it (probably `gcc -c filename.cpp`).

Comment: +1 This does indeed sound like the easiest way. problem is I am relatively new to the gnu build chain tools (I come from a windows background). Can you give a little example on what to place in the install section for a 'helloworld' application?. MTIA

Comment: I added a description to the answer (since makefile syntax requires line breaks).

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu uses the Debian package format (.deb). The resulting package can target an architecture (such as i386, AMD64, etc) or be architecture independent.

Then you can install the resulting package with 'dpkg -i packagefile.deb' as root.

Now more to the point: I suggest you to look for information about how to make a Debian package. I'm sure there are plenty of good reference sites out there and also tools, such as this one: http://debcreator.cmsoft.net/